# Elasticsearch + Kibana, sorting on uri yields no results. (uri isn't analyzed)

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana

I have a log of HTTP requests, one of the fields is a URI field. I want to get the average duration in ms for each URI. I set the y-axis in Kibana to 
`"Aggregation: Average , Field: durationInMs"`.

For the x-axis I have

```
"Aggregation: terms, Field uri, Order by: metric average durationInMs, Order: descending: 5"
```

***Image to clarify:***

[image]

This gives me a result but it doesn't use the **entire** URI. It instead splits up the URI and matches parts of it. After a quick google I found "[Multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html)" and I have added a URI.raw field on my index. The analyzed field warning disappeared but I get **no** result at all.

Any hints or tips?

lsc-logs2 mapping:

```
{
  "lsc-logs2": {
    "mappings": {
      "httplogentry": {
        "properties": {
          "context": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "durationInMs": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "method": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "startTime": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "uri": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "version": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An example document:

```
{
    "_index": "lsc-logs2",
    "_type": "httplogentry",
    "_id": "1148440",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "startTime": "2016-08-22T10:30:57.2298086+02:00",
        "context": "contexturi",
        "method": "GET",
        "uri": "http://uri/plannings/unassigned?date=2016-08-22T03:58:57.168Z&page=1&pageSize=9999",
        "username": "user",
        "source": "192.168.1.82",
        "durationInMs": 171.83710000000002,
        "status": 200,
        "id": 1148440,
        "version": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you reindexed your data after adding the raw field?

Comment: I stumbled accross this on the net as well, the only re-indexing we could find however was /_reindex and changing the source and dest like this:

{
  "source": {
    "index": "lsc-logs"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "lsc-logs2"
  }
}

That took around 5 hours and still didn't yield a result. I refreshed the field list in kibana too. Any ideas?

Comment: But the index pattern you have in Kibana is still working on the source index, i.e. `lsc-logs` and not your new index `lsc-logs2` right?

Comment: No I switched Kibana to lsc-logs2, even set it as the default, and when creating a visualization I get the choice of which one I want, I selected lsc-logs2. indexPattern in the url is set to lsc-logs2 too: http://imgur.com/a/4lvhT

Comment: Can you run this query and tell me if you get some result? `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/lsc-logs2/_search -d '{"size":0, "aggs":{"uris":{"terms":{"field":"uri.raw"}}}}'`

Comment: I got:

{
  "took": 74,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1000000,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "uris": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
}

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping you have in the `lsc-logs2` index + a sample document ?

Comment: I added the mapping, not sure what you mean by sample document though.

Comment: One document that is stored in your `lsc-logs2` index

Comment: Added the document, changed both uri's so they don't include possible confidential info :)

Comment: If you've reindexed the data, I'm surprised that my aggregation above doesn't yield anything then

Comment: If by reindexing you  mean executing: "{ "source": { "index": "lsc-logs" }, "dest": { "index": "lsc-logs2" } } " then yeah, I've done that. I could do it again (lsc-logs2 to lsc-logs3?) if you want (will take 4+ hours and it's a friday so that would probably mean I get back to you on monday)

Comment: That won't be necessary. Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: I'm curious to know at which point you added the `raw` field into your mapping. Did you create `lsc-logs2` with the proper mapping and only then reindexed the data or did you let reindex create the `lsc-logs2` index and then changed your mapping?

Comment: I added the raw field onto lsc-logs, then I did a reindex to lsc-logs2.

Comment: Aah ! That's it!  The mapping from `lsc-logs` doesn't get ported over to `lsc-logs2` when reindexing. You need to create the destination index first with the proper mapping and only then reindex the data.

Comment: Before I mess up and start a 4+ hour reindex again, what command do I have to send?

Comment: Let me write answer, it'll be more legible.

Comment: Alright, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reindexing data, the `httplogentry` mapping doesn't get ported from `lsc-logs` to `lsc-logs2`, you need to create the destination index+mapping first and only then reindex.

First delete the current destination index

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/lsc-logs2
```

Then create it anew by specifying the proper mapping

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/lsc-logs2 -d '{
    "mappings": {
      "httplogentry": {
        "properties": {
          "context": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "durationInMs": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "method": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "startTime": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "uri": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "version": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}'
```

Then you can reindex your data:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_reindex -d '{
  "source": {
    "index": "lsc-logs"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "lsc-logs2"
  }
}'
```

Then refresh your the fields in your index pattern in Kibana and it should work.

Comment: It's running these things right now, might take a while :P
Already confirmed in Kibana that the raw field shows up on the new index :D

Comment: While it's running, you should already be able to check in Kibana if it works, you don't need all the data to test it

Comment: Thats what I though and I tried it but it's still giving me the No results found message :/

Comment: Make sure your time window is big enough since you don't have yet all the data

Comment: Yes we did! However when I create a new index (lsc-logs3) and fill it using a bulk request on c#'s library (nest and es.net)  the raw uri isn't filled. Do I HAVE to reindex it even when I insert new data?

Comment: Did you pre-create the `lsc-logs3` index with the proper mapping **before indexing** new documents?

Comment: Yes I did, I used your script :)

Comment: And you made sure to replace `2` by `3` everywhere, right? Can you share the mapping of `lsc-logs3`?

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is that you have two mapping types in the same index (`httplogentry` and `elasticlogentry`) both having a field named `uri` but one has the raw sub-field and the other doesn't. That's a problem. Which one are you indexing through C#? I bet it's `elasticlogentry`

Comment: I suspect you are right, the model name was elasticlogentry, going to try and fix it real quick. I'll report back.

Comment: That did it, you're a genius! Thanks again.

Comment: Question, why did you not upvote the initial question? I'm trying to figure out exactly when to upvote a post. I saw that you were a member with lots of points so I thought I'd shoot in this quick question.

Comment: Done, given the long history of this question I might have forgotten in the end ;-)

Comment: Right, so am I right in assuming I should upvote if the question is detailed enough? Thats what I'm doing right now haha.

Comment: Excellent as usual!